# Web Essentials Bundling and the Act of Rendering the Files

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification, web-essentials

I am using the excellent Web Essentials visual studio extension by Mads. One of the functionalities that the Web Essentials extension contains is an ability to create a CSS bundle http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling

This results in the creation of an XML file which contains configuration information as to the bundling operation. It also creates a min file for the css.

The question I have relates to whether this differs from the normal bundling scenario in the context of the way it is invoked. In the normal bundle scenario which uses a BundleConfig class, to render the CSS you will use ***@Styles.Render("~/Content/CrispCSS")***

The big advantage of that being that it renders the individual files in Debug mode and the Bundled file in Release mode.

I have not been able to use ***@Styles.Render("~/Content/CrispCSS")***  for bundles which I have created using Web Essentials. It is certainly easy to use normal script tags and incorporate a path to the full  css file or the minified version. The disadvantage of this being that you have to manage that as a deployment step, rather than just being able to rely on the min version being used when the normal Bundling scenario is used.

Is that the cost benefit analysis for the Web Essentials bundling? In fact, I’m not really sure what the benefit is. You certainly get a minified file. But you lose the automatic debug/release toggle which occurs if you use BundleConfig.

Please let me know if I have got this wrong and you can use the normal Optimisation API to render your XML-based bundle.

Thanks